# Раскраска ячеек таблицы в зависимости от значения другого свойства объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Переписываю старый Delphi проект на WPF. Минимальный пример - объект с двумя свойствами - значение и цвет, причем цвет в формате Delphi (например "$000AFF00", "$001AAFCF"). Хочу изменять фон ячейки в столбце Value, в зависимости от значения в свойстве Color. Проблема в том, что значения Color могут быть любые, для этого написал конвертер, но вот как красить в этом случае столбец Value не понимаю.

```
public class ValueColor
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Конвертер для преобразования цвета из Delphi в C#.

```
public class Delphi2SharpColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string delphiColorPattern = @"(\$)([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte redByte = 0, greenByte = 0, blueByte = 0;

        var resultColor = Colors.Transparent;
        var stringValue = value as string;

        if (stringValue != null)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(delphiColorPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var match = regex.Match(stringValue);

            var blueValue = match.Groups[3].Value;
            var greenValue = match.Groups[4].Value;
            var redValue = match.Groups[5].Value;

            redByte = byte.Parse(redValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            greenByte = byte.Parse(greenValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            blueByte = byte.Parse(blueValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

            resultColor = Color.FromRgb(redByte, greenByte, blueByte);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(resultColor);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<DataGrid
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">

  <DataGrid.Resources>
            <converters:Delphi2SharpColorConverter x:Key="Deplhi2SharpColorConverter" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource Deplhi2SharpColorConverter}}" Value="$000AFF00">
                                <!-- Как тут быть? Чтобы красилось по значению из конвертера? -->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Color}" Header="Color" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value" Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource Deplhi2SharpColorConverter}}">`

Comment: @АндрейNOP У меня не получается сделать Background=... для DataGridColumn. Нет у колонки такого свойства. И даже если бы было, это же вся колонка бы красилась, разве нет? А нужна раскраска ячеек, в каждой строке таблицы.

Comment: Да, проверил. Сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто привяжите фон ячейки к значению через конвертер, никакие триггеры при этом не нужны:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Color,
                        Converter={StaticResource Deplhi2SharpColorConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```