# DataGrid закрасить ячейку

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли в WPF с помощью DataGridRowEventArgs закрасить определеную ячейку?

Как закрасить всю строку нашел(код ниже)

```
private void MainDG_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        if(условие) 
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        }

    }
```

Comment: А что за условие? По идее делать это надо в разметке с помощью триггера или конвертера

Comment: Условие я добавил образно, планирунтся из бд брать значение по которому и будет раскрашиваться ячейка

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843768/218063

Comment: А то что я использую AutoGeneratingColumn не помешает?

Comment: Не должно, стиль ячейки можно задать в `DatGrid.CellStyle`